# box api direct link for music file

Tags: box-api

dropbox has /media api that provides a direct link to be used for audio steaming with html5 audio tag. I do not see similar thing with box.

the real problem is that I cant use "GET /files/{file id}/content" for music streaming because it requires BoxAuth in header.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Direct download link is only available for paid box users not for the free user. So if you are free user then you have to upgrade your account to paid user and then after you will get the direct download link. See the box support answer  [here](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200519908-Direct-Linking-to-a-File)

Or else you can use the download api. See the [documentation](https://box-content.readme.io/#download-a-file)

This link is only valid for 15 minutes so after 15 minutes you have to again call the download api and you will get the fresh direct download link valid for next 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

When you [create a shared link](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file) for the file, a direct download link is also returned i.e. the `download_url` field in the following JSON:

```
{
    "type":"file",
    "id":"2192049121",
    "sequence_id":"1",
    "name":"brand_new_name.psd",
    "description":"",
    "size":1266400,
    "path":"\/brand_new_name.psd",
    "path_id":"\/0\/2192049121",
    "created_at":"2012-06-04T21:32:20-07:00",
    "modified_at":"2012-06-04T21:32:21-07:00",
    "shared_link": {
       "url": "https://www.box.com/s/0bb6907e48920c98d484",
       "download_url": "https://dl.boxcloud.com/shared/static/0bb6907e48920c98d484.webdoc",
       "password_enabled": false,
       "unshared_at": null,
       "download_count": 0,
       "preview_count": 0,
       "access": "Open",
       "permissions": {
           "download": true,
           "preview": true
       }
   }
    "etag":"72e96dad26aa67a5f7435548c86b7a8a331f0ae9",
    "created_by":
    {
        "type":"user",
        "id":"13344957",
        "name":"Sean Rose",
        "login":"sean+test@box.com"
    },
    "modified_by":
    {
        "type":"user",
        "id":"13344957",
        "name":"Sean Rose",
        "login":"seanrose@stanford.edu"
    },
    "owned_by":
    {
        "type":"user",
        "id":"13344957",
        "name":"Sean Rose",
        "login":"seanrose@stanford.edu"
    },
    "parent":
    {
        "type":"folder",
        "id":"0",
        "sequence_id":null,
        "name":"All Files"
    }
}
```